# JavaScript Error in Pentaho - Cannot call method "toUpperCase" of null

Tags: javascript, null, pentaho, spoon

// Sets all the letters as uppercase

```
var str = ae_a_asset_e$manufacture_code.toUpperCase();
var str2 = ae_a_asset_e$serial_no.toUpperCase();
var str3 = ae_a_asset_e$manu_part_number.toUpperCase();
var str4 = ae_a_asset_e$region_code.toUpperCase();
var str5 = ae_a_asset_e$fac_id.toUpperCase();
```

Any idea how to fix this? I would think there would have to be a way to say if value = null then don't worry about it.

Comment: "I would think there would have to be a way to say if value = null then don't worry about it.", Yes there is, have you tried implementing that?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Brand new to all this.

Comment: if(null != ae_a_asset_e$manufacture_code)

Comment: var str = (if (ae_a_asset_e$manufacture_code) == null) ? (true block) :  : (else ae_a_asset_e$manufacture_code.toUpperCase()))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to think whether it is correct that some values are `null` or not, such as `ae_a_asset_e$manufacture_code`.

If they can be `null` you can access them in a safe way like this (extend this code to all other vars as required):

```
var str = ae_a_asset_e$manufacture_code ? ae_a_asset_e$manufacture_code.toUpperCase() : "";
```

If they cannot be `null` then, your should check your data integrity first and then run this script (assuming they are never `null`).

Comment: I'm doing an excel input and some of the columns don't have data which is fine. Just need the code to look past the null values.

Comment: OK, then the code I posted should be perfectly fine for your scenario.

Comment: var str = ae_a_asset_e$manufacture_code ? ae_a_asset_e$manufacture_code.toUpperCase() : "";
var str2 = ae_a_asset_e$serial_no ? ae_a_asset_e$serial_no.toUpperCase() : "";
var str3 = ae_a_asset_e$manu_part_number ? ae_a_asset_e$manu_part_number.toUpperCase() : "";
var str4 = ae_a_asset_e$region_code ? ae_a_asset_e$region_code.toUpperCase() : "";
var str5 = ae_a_asset_e$fac_id ? ae_a_asset_e$fac_id.toUpperCase() : "";

Look better?

Comment: You are welcome! and please, consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry, new to stackoverflow as well. Accepted it! thanks again.